# Showing the positivity of $p$-adic density of zeroes of a polynomial

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ and $p$ be a prime. Let $\nu_t(p)$ denote the number of solutions $\mathbf{x} \in ((\mathbb{Z}/p^t \mathbb{Z}))^*)^n$
to the congruence
$$
f( \mathbf{x} ) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^t}.
$$
We define (something similar to the $p$-adic density)
$$
\mu(p) = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{  p^t \nu_t(p) }{ \phi(p^t)^n }.
$$
Could someone please explain how to show
$$
\mu(p) > 0
$$
provided the equation $f( \mathbf{x} ) = 0$ has a non-singular solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$, the units of $p$-adic integers?
Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any partial results? Have you proved it for $n=1$? $n=2$?

Comment: @Lubin I tried working with the definitions, but I couldn't quite figure it out. No, I don't have partial results yet. I would greatly appreciate any hint/suggestions also. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JohnnyT. : Please note the proper use of \pmod, as in my edit to your question.  You added spacing manually before "mod" by using a backslash and after "mod" by putting a blank space in \text{}, and added parentheses manually. What is there is now coded as f( \mathbf{x} ) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^t} and the result is this: $$f( \mathbf{x} ) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^t}$$  If there's only a single character after \pmod then the {curly braces} are not needed.  E.g. a\equiv b\pmod c yields this: $$a\equiv b\pmod c$$ Something like \delta is a single character for these purposes,${}\,\ldots\,\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$so that a\equiv b\pmod\delta yields this: $$a\equiv b\pmod\delta$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I wasn't aware of this command before. It is much easier than what I was doing. Thank you very much for letting me know and editing the question!